# htaccess equivalent code to javascript conditional code

Tags: javascript, regex, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I wonder if is there something htaccess code equivalent to following javascript code.

I moved a wordpress site and it lost some permalink plugin. I remember the plugin name but I wouldn't like to use it again because I want my site with less plugin as much as it can be. The problem after moving site is showing too many not found errors in GWM.

I'm new to htaccess and I can do redirection by using "Redirect 301". But if I redirect by using this, there will be so many redirect lines in .htaccess. I don't want too many lines in htaccess too. Then I use javascript to redirect and I got a working javascript code as below

```
$(function(){
        var url = this.location.href;
        var last_char = url.substring(url.length - 1);
        var last_five = url.substring(url.length - 5);
        if(!(/category/i.test(url)) && !(last_five=="blog/") && !(last_five=="html/") && last_char == "/"){
            var result = url.substring(0, url.length - 1);
            top.location.href = result+".html";
        }
    });
```

It redirect though after showing a 404 page. I don't want visitors to see 404 page and I thought htaccess might be helped but I don't know how to write. I write above javascript code because

1. Most of not found pages are just needed to be removed last slash (/)
   character and then append ".html"
2. category pages don't need to append ".html"
3. ".html/" (ending with slash but fine pages don't need to be redirected)
4. my blog home page is (myurl.com/blog/) but It doesn't need to remove
   slash and append .html

Thanks in advance for all answers!

Comment: I asked on [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/questions/580797/htaccess-conditional-statement) also but got no answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use this equivalent rule in .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /category/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !blog/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !html/$
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.html [L,R]
```

Comment: That is very informative. What URL did you try? What is location of .htaccess and what is not working. If you want help spend few minutes to describe your current state of problem.

Comment: I'm really sorry. I thought I don't need to describe locaction of .htaccess since "Redirect 301" is working. It is same level with the root index file (`myurl.com`). I was installed wordpress at (`myurl.com/blog`). Since .htaccess file within (`myurl.com/blog`) not working, I use root level one. Please let me know of you need more information.

I tried for `http://www.mywebsite.com/blog/foo-bar-foo-foo/` but it doesn't redirect to `http://www.mywebsite.com/blog/foo-bar-foo-foo.html/`

Comment: 1. You never told about presence of WP 2. I cannot presume anything until you present all facts. 3. If there is a `/blog/.htaccess` file then above rule in root .htacess won't be effective for `/blog/` URL. And in any case above rule has `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !blog/$` which means don't run for `/blog/` directory same as your JS code. You can use this rule for non `/blog/` URL.

Comment: Sir, I stated that `I move a wordpress site` in my question second line!  

- I put your code in `root/.htaccess` and disabled `root/blog/.htaccess`, still not working  -I put your code in `root/blog/.htaccess`, not working also. What should I do?  - the following code included in `/blog/.htaccess`  `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>`

Comment: For which URL it doesn't work? Place updated rule as first rule in `/blog/.htaccess` below `RewriteBase /blog/`